# Using Powershell OUT-FILE changes data

Tags: powershell

Here is sample code that displays physical disk info on the console (with much thanks to guyc@computerperformance.co.uk):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | % {
  $disk = $_
  $partitions = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
                "{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'} " +
                "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
  Get-WmiObject -Query $partitions | % {
    $partition = $_
    $drives = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
              "{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='$($partition.DeviceID)'} " +
              "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
    Get-WmiObject -Query $drives | % {
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Disk        = $disk.DeviceID
        DiskModel   = $disk.Model
        Partition   = $partition.Name
        DriveLetter = $_.DeviceID
        VolumeName  = $_.VolumeName
        Size        = "{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]
            FreeSpace   = "{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I want the console output to go to a TXT file.  When I introduce "Out-File", nothing goes on the console, but the output is different.  It doesn't divide (into GB) and displays different fields than what I selected.  Here is what I changed:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | % {
  $disk = $_
  $partitions = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
                "{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'} " +
                "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
  Get-WmiObject -Query $partitions | % {
    $partition = $_
    $drives = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
              "{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='$($partition.DeviceID)'} " +
              "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
    Get-WmiObject -Query $drives | **Out-File -filepath "d:\DiskInfo.txt" -append** | % {
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Disk        = $disk.DeviceID
        DiskModel   = $disk.Model
        Partition   = $partition.Name
        DriveLetter = $_.DeviceID
        VolumeName  = $_.VolumeName
        Size        = "{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]
        FreeSpace   = "{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I changed how I implemented the OUT-FILE (putting it on each output line):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | % {
  $disk = $_
  $partitions = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
                "{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'} " +
                "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
  Get-WmiObject -Query $partitions | % {
    $partition = $_
    $drives = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
              "{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='$($partition.DeviceID)'} " +
              "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
    Get-WmiObject -Query $drives | % {
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Disk        = $disk.DeviceID | Out-File -filepath "d:\DiskInfo.txt" -append  
        DiskModel   = $disk.Model | Out-File -filepath "d:\DiskInfo.txt" -append 
        Partition   = $partition.Name | Out-File -filepath "d:\DiskInfo.txt" -append 
        DriveLetter = $_.DeviceID | Out-File -filepath "d:\DiskInfo.txt" -append 
        VolumeName  = $_.VolumeName | Out-File -filepath "d:\DiskInfo.txt" -append 
        Size        = "{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float] | Out-File -filepath "d:\DiskInfo.txt" -append 
        FreeSpace   = "{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float] | Out-File -filepath "d:\DiskInfo.txt" -append 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it not only splits between console (headings) and TXT file (values), but also displays different variables than before, and doesn't do the division, just shows number of bytes, not GB.

Can someone set me straight on using OUT-FILE - or a better option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can someone set me straight on using `out-file`? are there other options?

You can just use the PowerShell [redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) operator `>>` at the end of the script.

```
    } >> DiskInfo.txt
```

If you want to use `out-file` then also put it at the end of the script.

```
    } | out-file Diskinfo.txt
```

Notes:

- Change `DiskInfo.txt` as appropiate.
- The advantage of using `out-file` is that parameters can be added to `out-file` but not `>>`

Get-Disk.ps1:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | % {
  $disk = $_
  $partitions = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
                "{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'} " +
                "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
  Get-WmiObject -Query $partitions | % {
    $partition = $_
    $drives = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
              "{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='$($partition.DeviceID)'} " +
              "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
    Get-WmiObject -Query $drives | % {
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Disk        = $disk.DeviceID
        DiskModel   = $disk.Model
        Partition   = $partition.Name
        DriveLetter = $_.DeviceID
        VolumeName  = $_.VolumeName
        Size        = "{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]
            FreeSpace   = "{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]
      }
    }
  }
} >> DiskInfo.txt
```

Example output:

```
PS F:\test> .\Get-Disk
PS F:\test> type .\DiskInfo.txt


Size        : 449.46
Partition   : Disk #0, Partition #2
FreeSpace   : 65.36
Disk        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
DiskModel   : WDC WD5000LPVX-08V0TT5
VolumeName  :
DriveLetter : C:

Size        : 59.61
Partition   : Disk #2, Partition #0
FreeSpace   : 37.13
Disk        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2
DiskModel   : SanDisk Cruzer USB Device
VolumeName  : SANDISK
DriveLetter : E:

Size        : 2794.51
Partition   : Disk #1, Partition #0
FreeSpace   : 1648.17
Disk        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
DiskModel   : Seagate Expansion Desk USB Device
VolumeName  : Expansion
DriveLetter : F:



PS F:\test>
```

---

#### about_Redirection

```
The Windows PowerShell redirection operators are as follows.

Operator  Description                Example  
--------  ----------------------     ------------------------------
>         Sends output to the        Get-Process > Process.txt
          specified file.

>>        Appends the output to      dir *.ps1 >> Scripts.txt
          the contents of the  
          specified file.

2>        Sends errors to the        Get-Process none 2> Errors.txt
          specified file.

2>>       Appends errors to          Get-Process none 2>> Save-Errors.txt
          the contents of the 
          specified file.

2>&1      Sends errors (2) and       Get-Process none, Powershell 2>&1
          success output (1) 
          to the success 
          output stream.

3>        Sends warnings to the      Write-Warning "Test!" 3> Warnings.txt
          specified file.

3>>       Appends warnings to        Write-Warning "Test!" 3>> Save-Warnings.txt
          the contents of the 
          specified file.

3>&1      Sends warnings (3) and     function Test-Warning 
          success output (1)         {  Get-Process PowerShell; 
          to the success                Write-Warning "Test!" }
          output stream.             Test-Warning 3>&1

4>        Sends verbose output to    Import-Module * -Verbose 4> Verbose.txt
          the specified file.

4>>       Appends verbose output     Import-Module * -Verbose 4>> Save-Verbose.txt
          to the contents of the 
          specified file.

4>&1      Sends verbose output (4)   Import-Module * -Verbose 4>&1
          and success output (1)    
          to the success output
          stream.              

5>        Sends debug messages to    Write-Debug "Starting" 5> Debug.txt
          the specified file.

5>>       Appends debug messages     Write-Debug "Saving" 5>> Save-Debug.txt
          to the contents of the 
          specified file.

5>&1      Sends debug messages (5)   function Test-Debug 
          and success output (1)     { Get-Process PowerShell 
          to the success output        Write-Debug "PS" }
          stream.                    Test-Debug 5>&1

*>        Sends all output types     function Test-Output
          to the specified file.     { Get-Process PowerShell, none  
                                       Write-Warning "Test!"
*>>       Appends all output types     Write-Verbose "Test Verbose"
          to the contents of the       Write-Debug "Test Debug" } 
          specified file.            
                                     Test-Output *> Test-Output.txt
*>&1      Sends all output types     Test-Output *>> Test-Output.txt
          (*) to the success output  Test-Output *>&1      
          stream.
```

Source [about_Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx)

Comment: Wow, that was almost too easy.  I wish I had see that.  Thanks so much, I really appreciate it.  And, I have learned, the easy way is the best.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that I can "accept the answer" anywhere on the screen.  Point me to it and you get the points - with my appreciation.

Comment: ahh, got it.  not obvious.  but then, I'm a newbie to the forum.  thanks.

Comment: instead of `>> DiskInfo.txt` you can also use `| out-file D:\diskinfo.txt` to stick with the more "powershelly" way. Another pro for this is you can add parameters to `out-file` but you can't add parameters to `>>`

Comment: @SimonS Hmm. I thought I tried that and got an error. I must have done something wrong. Thanks for the note, I will update the answer.

Comment: @JCauble Answer updated to show how to use `out-file`